# How to chain #has functional helper for {{else has}}

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I am trying to achieve {{else has}} same like "else if" in handlebars theme of ghost.io but I am facing an issue but it works as expected.

```
{{#primary_tag}}
    {{#has slug="first-slug"}}
      <h1>in slug 1</h1>
    {{else has slug="slug-2"}}
    <h2>In Slug 2</h2>
      {{else}}
      {{!-- TTC Modal - otherwise this --}}
     <h3>In other slug</h3>
    {{/has}}
{{/primary_tag}}
```

I am following the https://docs.ghost.org/api/handlebars-themes/helpers/has/ but  there is no proper for  {{else has}}